# How to call print from otherwise in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have dataframe where I'm checking the condition and accordingly I'm performing the operation.I'm using "when and otherwise" function where I'm trying to print failed result in "otherwise" but it is not printing.Any help will be appreciating.

```
joinDF=
+--------+-------------+----------+--------+-------+
|   ID   |     A       |      B   |  C     |  D    |
+--------+-------------+----------+--------+-------+
|    9574|            F|    005912| 2016022|     10|
|    9576|            F|    005912| 2016022|     21|
|    9578|            F|    005912| 2016022|      0|
|    9580|            F|    005912| 2016022|     19|
|    9582|            F|    005912| 2016022|     89|
+--------+-------------+----------+--------+-------+

joinDF
.withColumn("Validate",when(joinDF("D") =!= 0 ,lit(ture)).otherwise(print(joinDF("ID"))))
```

Comment: Otherwise returns a column/literal and it doesn't and can't print. This code won't execute. Read the documentation please http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$

Comment: @eliasah thanks for your reply, how can I print the column if my condition is failed.

Comment: When you say "print" - what exactly do you mean? What do you expect to happen? If you mean "_use_ value X as the column's value", then see @eliasah`s answer; If you mean you want it printed to console - which console is it? Spark is a distributed framework, the values will be printed into many separate consoles (on the various worker machines) and not necessarily into the driver's console (the machine initiating this job), so it will likely be rather useless.

Comment: @TzachZohar means I wanted to print into my console.

Comment: And which console is that - is it important that it's printed to the _driver_ console, or is it OK if it's printed into the several worker consoles (each ID in a different console, meaning you won't see the entire list of bad IDs in one place)?

Answer (score 1):

It quite simple and very straight-forward :

```
Seq(("A",1),("B",0)).toDF("key","value")
    .withColumn("verdict", when($"value"=!=0, lit("true")).otherwise("false")).show
+---+-----+-------+
|key|value|verdict|
+---+-----+-------+
|  A|    1|   true|
|  B|    0|  false|
+---+-----+-------+
```

You don't need `if`, `else` or `udf`s

With your example :

```
Seq(("A",1),("B",0)).toDF("ID","D").withColumn("validate",when($"D" =!= 0 ,lit("true")).otherwise($"ID")).show

+---+---+--------+
| ID|  D|validate|
+---+---+--------+
|  A|  1|    true|
|  B|  0|       B|
+---+---+--------+
```

Comment: if my condition is failed then I wanted to print ID column value instead false

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to print the value if they did not matched than you can create `udf` as below

```
val validate = udf((value :String )=>
{
  //if if value is not equal to 0 return true else print value and return it
  if (value != 0) "true"
  else {
    print(s"value = ${value}")
    value
  }
})

//this adds new column named validate and calls the udf validate

joinDF.withColumn("Validate", validate($"ID"))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have some restriction, I can't use udf in my code.Please let me know is it possible through when and otherwise?

Comment: @thehacker if you can't write a udf, the only option is to store the value in the table and then select it later like in eliasah's answer